# Android ?attr/colorPrimary not working on call to setTheme

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-theme

I have an android app with 2 themes. And the user is able to switch themes from a settings activity elsewhere in the app. The default theme is `AppThemeBlue` and when the app starts up all is well. However after user changes theme from settings activity to the `AppThemeGreen` no change is made.
Here are my 2 themes in the `style.xml`

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppThemeBlue" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/BlueColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/BlueColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/BlueColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>`

    <style name="AppThemeGreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/GreenColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/GreenColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/GreenColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

my `main_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeBlue.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:titleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppThemeBlue.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my code in the `ActivityMain`

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected static FloatingActionButton mFloatingActionButton;
    protected static Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mMainContentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_bg);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        setTheme();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        setTheme();
    }

    public void setTheme() {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityMain.this);
        String color = sp.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.themes_key), null);
        if (color != null) {
            switch (color) {
                case ConstentValues.COLORBLUE: {
                    setStausBar(R.color.BlueColorPrimaryDarkStatus);
                    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeBlue);
                    break;
                }
                case ConstentValues.COLORGREEN: {
                    setStausBar(R.color.GreenColorPrimaryDarkStatus);
                    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeGreen);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            setStausBar(R.color.BlueColorPrimaryDarkStatus);
            setTheme(R.style.AppThemeBlue);
        }
    }

    private void setStausBar(int color) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = ActivityMain.this.getWindow();
            window.setStatusBarColor(ActivityMain.this.getResources().getColor(color));
        }
    }
}
```

Is it becase I have `?attr/mycolor` in my `main_layout.xml`? If so, please explain what is the problem with the ?attr because in the `style.xml` both themes have the same item names.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: try restarting the activity and updating the theme before just before setContentView

Comment: link: http://mrbool.com/how-to-change-the-layout-theme-of-an-android-application/25837

Answer (score 1):

If your activity theme set only once then call the setTheme() method before super.onCreate() and setContentView().

If you want to change the theme at runtime, ie. through a button click, then you need to restart the activity.

Read [this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-changing-app-theme-at-runtime-ab17d3eb93cc) for more information about changing themes at runtime.